# Python stops working on manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django

I am new to stackoverflow, very new to Python and trying to learn Django.
I am on Windows 10 and running commands from powershell (as administrator). 
I am in a virtual environment.  I am trying to set up Django. 
I have run the following commands
"pip install Django"
"django-admin.py startproject learning_log ."
"python manage.py migrate"

All of the above seemed to work okay, however, when I then try to run the command
"python manage.py runserver"
I get a popup error box that says:
Python has stopped working
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.
Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

Can someone tell me how to resolve this issue or where to look for any error messages that might clue me in as to what is causing the problem?

Comment: That sounds like an issue with the installation of python itself. Can you run just `python` and correctly load a shell?

Comment: Try restarting your windows.

Comment: I restarted windows, rebooted my lapttop.  I am able to run python.  I imported json and loaded some numbers into a file.  However, I still get the same problem at the "python manage.py runserver"

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the "python manage.py runserver" command to work. The only thing different I did was before setting up the virtual env and installing Django was set my executionpolicy to Unrestricted. Previously it had been set to RemoteSigned. I hadn't been gettiing any warning or errors but thought I would try it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. After trying everything, I switched from PS to cmd, cd to the same directory and run `python manage.py runserver`. Then it worked. Then I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> quit the server, switched back to PS, ran the command, it still threw the same dialog window (Python stopped working). Then I went back to cmd, typed the command and the server started fine.

Conclusion: Use cmd to run the command, not PS.